# Dealing with special characters in a text search using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, full-text-search

I'm trying to achieve a specific search in my application, and I've run into a bit of trouble.

I want the first results in my search to contain the phrase that was searched for *first*, instead of just containing it.

For example, if I search for parts in my application, I get these results:

```
Add-On Windshield Wiper Kit
Turn Signal / Headlight / Windshield Wiper/Washer Combination Lever Set
Turn Signal / Headlight / Windshield Wiper/Washer Combination Switch and Lever Set
Windshield Wiper / Washer Circuit Breaker
Windshield Wiper / Washer Dash Indicator Light
Windshield Wiper Arm
```

Whereas I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
Windshield Wiper Arm
Windshield Wiper / Washer Circuit Breaker
Windshield Wiper / Washer Dash Indicator Light
Add-On Windshield Wiper Kit
Turn Signal / Headlight / Windshield Wiper/Washer Combination Lever Set
Turn Signal / Headlight / Windshield Wiper/Washer Combination Switch and Lever Set
```

Notice how Windshield Wiper Arm is the first result because it contains the search parameters (which is simply "Windshield Wiper") and a follow-up word that begins with the letter A.

Anyway, here's my model:

```
class Pcdb::Part < CatalogsRecord
  include PgSearch
  self.table_name = "parts"
  belongs_to :parts_description
  pg_search_scope :search_for_parts, against: :part_terminology_name, using: { tsearch: { dictionary: "simple", normalization: 2 } }
end
```

And the relevant part of my controller:

```
Pcdb::Part.where('lower(parts.part_terminology_name) like ?', "%#{search}%").reorder("parts.part_terminology_name ASC")
```

In this particular instance, the `search` variable is `Windshield Wiper`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a conditional to your ordering expression, checking whether the name started with the search term, and ordering those results first i.e. (as SQL)

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN parts.part_terminology_name LIKE 'Windshield Wiper%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    parts.part_terminology_name
```

If you want to get more sophisticated about ordering, you could use regex to ensure that parts with the phrase followed by a word sorted before those with the phrase followed by a symbol (i.e. `Windshield Wiper Arm` before `Windshield Wiper / Washer Circuit Breaker`)

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN parts.part_terminology_name = 'Windshield Wiper' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN parts.part_terminology_name ~ '^Windshield Wiper [a-z]' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN parts.part_terminology_name LIKE 'Windshield Wiper%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    parts.part_terminology_name
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fc3ea9/2)

Comment: Hey, this looks good, but I'm trying to have similar results with other search terms as well. I'm looking for a way to generalize a solution.

Comment: @rustyshackleford I've just used `Windshield Wiper` because I wanted to make an SQL demo and I can't pass parameters to it. You would use `?` placeholders for those values and for the first query pass `"#{search}%"` and for the second query pass `"#{search}"`, `"^#{search} [a-z]"` and `"#{search}%"`